# Java code not executing. It is getting stuck at CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(plsql);

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

It seems like `callable` statement is not getting executed in the following code.

```
Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection(schema,uName,pwd);
String plsql =" " +
    "BEGIN " +
    "   for crec in (select distinct filename from flex_template) loop " +
    "   Update vfs3 set created=sysdate where name =crec.filename;" +
    "   Update vfs3_data set data =(select data from vfs3_data@uktest02 where file_id in (select file_id from vfs3@uktest02 where name=crec.filename )) where file_id in (select file_id from vfs3 where name=crec.filename) ;" +
    "   end loop;" +
    "END;" ;                         

CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(plsql); 
System.out.println("After plsql prpare call");

cs.execute();         
con.commit();   
System.out.println("File updated successfully");  

cs.close();
con.close();
```

I want to run the plsql begin end block in oracle database. Could anyone please advise how this can be accomplished..

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Instead of doing a slow and inefficient loop (doing row-by-row updates), you should run two simple `update` statements. I'm sure that will be a lot faster.

Comment: Most probably your code is actually working, but is awfully slow because of this inefficient row-by-row processing of the data. How many rows does `select distinct filename from flex_template` return. The updates (including the sub-selects through the DBlink) are executed once for each row in the cursor. So instead of running `select data from vfs3_data@uktest02 ...` only **once**, this is run again and again and again, ....

Comment: Also, are you sure that the scalar subquery `(select data from vfs3_data@uktest02 where file_id in (select file_id from vfs3@uktest02 where name=crec.filename))` is returning exactly zero or one rows for any given `crec.filename`? If not, the update would fail with `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what CallableStatement allows you to do. 
It's designed to call existing stored procedures, not to allow you to execute ad-hoc blocks of PL/SQL code.
Define your PL/SQL as a stored procedure in the database, then use CallableStatement to execute that stored procedure (optionally passing in any parameters you need).

Check the javadoc for CallableStatement for details about the exact syntax requirements for the call.

Comment: This is not true, an anonymous PL/SQL block can (and should, I think) be executed through a `CallableStatement`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not according to the API documentation. That talks exclusively about calling stored procecures, and how it abstracts those away in a database independent syntax.

Comment: Then what is the correct way of running an anonymous PL/SQL block in your opinion? Actually I'm pretty sure the code does what it is supposed to do. But the highly inefficient row-by-row (aka "slow-by-slow") processing is most probably the real reason: it works, just _awfully_ slow.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it might work, but not according to the JDBC API docs. If it does, it's a driver specific thing in the Oracle driver (and may well depend on which driver is used, thin or OCI). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html mentions this as being Oracle specific...

Comment: An anonymous PL/SQL is for all purposes and intent the same as a stored procedure (especially at the abstraction level of a JDBC driver). It just doesn't have a name and is "temporary" in that it "vanishes" once the statement is done (and it doesn't matter whether it's the thin or the OCI driver)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#34_01